# Generating Thumbnails for .ppt and .pptx in PHP

Tags: php, powerpoint, imagick

Is it possible to generate thumbnails for .PPT and .PPTX files using PHP? I am currently doing the same for images and pdf files but hitting walls when it comes to power point presentations.

I am currently using Imagick for the PDF using the code below.

```
        if(in_array($ext,array('pdf'))){

                $pdf = './uploads/'.$new_file_name; 
                $filename=str_replace($ext,'jpg',$new_file_name);
                $img = new imagick($pdf);               
                for ($x = 1;$x <= $img->getNumberImages(); $x++) {      
                    $save_to = './uploads/'.$x.'-'.$filename;
                    $img->setIteratorIndex($x);
                    $img->setImageFormat('jpg');                
                    $geo=$img->getImageGeometry();
                    $sizex=$geo['width'] / 2;
                    $sizey=$geo['height'] / 2; 
                    $img->resizeImage($sizex,$sizey,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
                    $img->writeImage($save_to);
                }
                $count = $img->getNumberImages();
                $update = '[pdf=/uploads/'.$new_file_name.']/uploads/'.$count.'-'.$filename.'[/pdf]'.$update;
            }
```

Comment: I don't know what facilities PHP offers, whether it can be assumed that PPT is installed, etc, but if you can automate PPT via COM, you can open the presentation and call the .Export method on each slide you want to create a thumbnail for.  .Export takes filename of exported image, image filter (ie, "JPG"), and the width and height of the image in pixels as parameters.

Comment: You may be able to glue something together using `libreoffice --convert-to pdf PPTXFILE`. It won't be pretty, though.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Or at least almost certainly not. You could call `\Imagick::queryformats();` to list the formats that Imagick, or rather ImageMagick, supports to double-check that PowerPoint formats are not supported, but as they aren't [listed as supported](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) then I doubt they will be.

It seems one of the best ways to do achieve the same thing is to use [unoconv](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv) to convert the PowerPoint file to PDF first:

unoconv -f pdf presentation.ppt

After that you would be able to manipulate it with Imagick.